# Adding custom handler-class to JSF custom component

Tags: jsf, custom-component

I want to add custom handler to my custom component,but i am using @FacesComponent annotation to provide the tag name and the namespace and i don't have an XML file to contains my component's information

```
public class MyHandler extends ComponentHandler
```

Normally people do the following:

```
<handler-class>MyHandler</handler-class>
```

How can i specify my handler-class in my custom component class?

Comment: Do you want to create a (ui) component? And what is your jsf version? Simce if I remember correctly there is no need to have a `handler-class` for ui-components

Comment: I'm using JSF v2.2 and yes there's no need to define ```handler-class``` ,but i need to defined one in order to override some methods in it.

Comment: Which methods? I did the same for primefaces components and There's No Need To Have A handler class en Sorry For The capitalization that is Something From Google Voice

Comment: I want to add a new method rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the book Mastering JavaServerFaces 2.2 i realized that there's no solution for this problem unless i have `taglib.xml` file.